# Sending gifts home during long trips

Tags: europe, international-travel, uzbekistan

I often move and I am almost never at home. I understand that many people are in the same situation. Please, tell me how you congratulate your family and friends at various occasions (birthday, Christmas,...), except phone calls, when you cannot visit them personally? My family lives in Uzbekistan and in the next 3 years I will not be able to visit them.

Comment: Buy something not too heavy, wrap it properly, head to a suitable post office a few weeks before the event, fill out the customs form and have it sent?

Comment: Give a trusted relative in Uzbekistan funds for 3 years worth of gifts before you go.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on various factors for example what is your budget, who is receiver and what kind of gifts you want to send.

One idea can be to use the local online shops, for the reason that it can be cheaper (especially the delivery costs) and have the products closer to your culture.

Comment: Ok,  my parents have anniversary. I want to send flowers for my mother and didn't yet think of a dad. A problem is in that, how I can send flowers, in fact them will not put in a box... I know a few delivery services, but I needed reviews about them